# SQL query returning values outside the specified range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, multiple-value

I have written a SQL query to return a `DocumentID` when a specific column from the same table has 4 defined values. The problem I have is that I need to define IDs from another column for each value to be sure I have an accurate return.

The query I have written is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    VV.[DocumentID], [Filename], [Path], D.LatestRevisionNo
FROM
    Documents D 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[DocumentsInProjects] DP ON DP.DocumentID = D.DocumentID 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Projects] P ON DP.ProjectID = P.ProjectID 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[VariableValue] VV ON VV.DocumentID = D.DocumentID
WHERE 
    VV.ValueText IN ('170', '316', '2.125', 'LOCK RING') 
GROUP BY 
    VV.DocumentID, D.Filename, P.Path, D.LatestRevisionNo
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ValueText) = 4 
    AND Filename LIKE '%sld%'
```

What I need is something like

```
(VV.variableID = 79 AND VV.ValueText = 'LOCK RING') 
AND (VV.variableID = 92 AND VV.ValueText = '316') 
AND (VV.variableID = 328 AND VV.ValueText = '2.125') 
AND (VV.variableID = 351 AND VV.ValueText = '170')
```

Comment: change `and` to `or` and I think you'll have what you're after  vv.variable can't be 79 and 92. and 328 on the same record.  it can however be 79 and lock ring OR 92 and 316.   `...= 'LOCK RING') 
OR (VV.v...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
(VV.variableID = 79 AND VV.ValueText = 'LOCK RING') 
OR (VV.variableID = 92 AND VV.ValueText = '316') 
OR (VV.variableID = 328 AND VV.ValueText = '2.125') 
OR (VV.variableID = 351 AND VV.ValueText = '170')
```

variableId can't be 79 and 92 and 328 and 351 all on the same record.  Thus or's are needed.

Comment: I understand the problem with AND. Thank you for the clarification.Will the "Having COUNT(DISTINCT ValueText) = 4" still force all values to be complete?

Comment: Yes it will.  The on distinct count on valuetext will ensure 4 unique values are present with the desired variableID's having the desired valuetext.  For a self taught, you've grasped some complicated issues very well here.  not many I work with understand `having count(Distinct field) = #` the way you've used it here

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very much for the fast help.